# How would I open multiple files, and combine one line of data from each document into a single number? Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have several files all named add_.txt with numbers from 1 -5 and I want to take the first line of information (a 1 by 5 matrix with all ones) from each file add them together, take this information and create a new text file with the result. Obviously the answer would simply be [5 5 5 5 5] but I would like to know how to program to get there.

Ive been able to teach myself how to "add" two data strings from the same document and create a text file with the answer with this code

```
fid=fopen('add.txt');
A = fgetl(fid);
AA = str2num(A)
B = fgets(fid);
BB = str2num(B)
C = AA + BB;
fclose(fid);
dlmwrite('results.txt', C)
```

but i do not know how to make the jump to automated calculations on a multi-file level, any help would be great.

Comment: Read the file in with `load(FILENAME, '-ascii')` and then go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
% List of file names
% (can be auto-generated like so: filename = ['add_' num2str(ii) '.txt']
% with ii your iteration variable)
filenames = {'add_1.txt', 'add_2.txt', 'add_3.txt', 'add_4.txt', 'add_5.txt'};

% If you know the size of the first line: 
A = zeros(1,5);

% Loop through all filenames
for filename = filenames
    fid = fopen(filename{1});
    A = A + str2num( fgetl(fid) );%#ok
    fclose(fid);    
end

% Write results to file
dlmwrite('results.txt', A);
```

If you *don't* know beforehand how many elements there are in `A`, you'll have to modify the loop a little bit:

```
A = 0;
for filename = filenames
    fid = fopen(filenames{1});
    A = A + str2num( fgetl(fid) );%#ok
    fclose(fid);    
end
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "otherwise youll have to use an if inside the loop? very lost. Also your code says "A = A + _______" which baffles me as well, could you explain that?

Comment: Don't forget about `load(FILENAME, '-ascii')`

Comment: @Aralo: And what if your 5 `FILENAME`s are 5 TB each? :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Premature optimization... :) (But yes, you're right. Thought I'd prefer clean code to optimized one).