# multiple cell array looping

Tags: matlab, for-loop, iteration, cell

I am wondering folks how can I loop over two different data cell arrays.

More precisely, The first

```
data1 = {'x','y','z', 'xyz','yxz'};
data2 = {'b','c','a'};
```

I want a for loop that performs the following operation

> **iterates on the first element of data2 while iterating over the entire elements of data1**

Hope you guys can understand my question and looking forward to your amazing talent

Thank you

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17049432/1698972) may help. However you need to use `nested for loop` for you case.

Comment: Thanx for your reply.. but need more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data1 = {'x','y','z', 'xyz','yxz'};
data2 = {'b','c','a'};

for k = data2
    for m = data1
        [k{1} m{1}] % Print or use them
    end
end
```

where `k` and `m` are `1x1` cell arrays, and you can access the string inside them with `k{1}` or `k{:}` (all the elements which is only 1 now).

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested `cellfun` depending on what you want to do with `data2{ii}` and `data1{jj}`...

```
res = cellfun( @( d1 ) cellfun( @( d2 ) myfun( d1, d2 ), data2, 'uni', 0 ), data1, 'uni', 0 );
```